# Add weekend day backgrounds

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using flatpicker calendar and want to make every weekend day's background #7a73aa. Unfortunately flatpicker does not add a class to weekend day's.

I've tried this with css but that's not working:

```
.dayContainer span:nth-child(6n) {
  background: #7a73aa;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Page source:

[image]

Any idea how I could do this with css?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: If this starts to go diagonally like that, then you obviously are taking into account one item too little. So that `6` would need to be a `7`, corresponding to how many days a week actually has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `6n` with `7n` to highlight sundays. Then add a rule for `7n-1` to highlight saturdays :

```js
flatpickr('#calendar', {
  "locale": {
    "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
  }
});
```

```css
.dayContainer > .flatpickr-day:nth-child(7n),
.dayContainer > .flatpickr-day:nth-child(7n-1) {
    background: #7a73aa;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.5.1/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" id="calendar">
```